# C++ Pointer being freed was not allocated. Not calling free

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory-management, free

I am writing a program that processes video input and after it runs for a while it sometimes exits with "pointer being freed was not allocated". However at no point in my program do I call free or malloc. I am passing objects of a class I defined around in vectors and the program uses pthreads to separate the input from the processing. Other than calling free twice on the same pointer without reallocating it in between what else could be causing this problem?

Unfortunately since it takes so long for the error to happen and because of the multithreading I don't know where this error is occurring so I can't include a sample of my code.

Comment: Yes,  the issue if from line 237 of `dec.c` file. [Hint: How we can tell without seeing the code?]

Comment: You're probably calling other functions which internally use free. But we can't tell if you don't provide any code.

Comment: freeing a rubbish pointer might be another cause

Comment: The type of app he is talking about probably has thousands of lines of code, any of which could be the problem.  It is understandable that he is not able to post any particular segment.

Comment: I am suspecting a sync problem between your threads.  Perhaps one of the library calls, on the processing side, tries to use one of the pointers, before it is allocated, is unable to use it, but still tries to free it.  Since you are not using free or malloc, this is the only thing I can guess at.

Comment: @Gilchrist You're right it's much too long to share all of it and I don't know where it is coming from to narrow it down.

Comment: I suspect that it is a sync problem. Could just accessing memory that hasn't been allocated be the problem? The application also uses opencv extensively if that helps

Comment: A debugger could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into using safe pointers provided in C++11. They do many good things, but for you the best use would be to take care of memory deallocation for you.

[This](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/) is the library that you will need to use.

From the little information that you have shared makes me believe that [Shared Pointer](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/) is what you are looking for (but do look at other classes as well, Weak Shared Pointer and Unique Pointer might be needed in some parts of your application).

If you have any other questions, please ask a specific question.

Comment: Thank you Volodya. I understand that my question wasn't very specific, sorry about that but I didn't know how to narrow it down more.

Comment: I'll check out the library but I don't explicitly do any memory management.